# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the Production Server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on VS 2010 asp.net c# application

My project is working on local machine, but when i deploy project on  production server its throws following error.

"The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

On my production server Office is not installed and it is not allowed to install. Please suggest to resolve this error.

So please suggest me what should i do?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to install the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works for me. But it worked for .xlsx file, if I select .xls file it giving me following error "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"

Comment: This could be because your app is targeting 64-bit and xls driver works only with 32-bit. A workaround is that you use the 32-bit version of Access Database Engine 2010 by forcing your .NET application to run in 32-bit mode (e.g. by selecting x86 platform in Configuration Manager)

Comment: If it is an asp.net app you may have to change the App Pool settings in to enable to 32-bit application.

Comment: I changed connection string for .xls as same as .xlsx, then it works for me.It is as follows. "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;'"

Comment: @user913947 - if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.